# Ansible: Install Qualys Cloud Agent in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, ansible

I've been trying to get this running but it just won't go for me.
Here's the thing, I need to install Qualys through Ansible and it's making me mad.
The script I've got (that works) is a powershell script and it's like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd /c .\QualysCloudAgent_4.6.1.6.exe CustomerId=$CId ActivationId=$AId WebServiceUri="http://qagpublic.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/CloudAgent/"}
```

Now, I've tried to use win_shell, win_powershell, win_raw, win_package...
I've tried to pass the parameters separately, to use become to become another user and elevate it.... but it just won't go.

It looks something like this what I need:

```
- name: Install Qualys Agent on the machine
  ansible.win_shell: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd /c C:\\_IDTDeploy\\SW\\Qualys\\QualysCloudAgent_4.6.1.6.exe CustomerId="'{'{{customer_id}}'}'" ActivationId="'{'{{activation_id}}'}'" WebServiceUri="http://qagpublic.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/CloudAgent/"}
```

I've tried this

```
- name: Install Qualys agent
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: "{{ installingpath46 }}"
    arguments:
    - ActivationId="'{'{{activation_id}}'}'"
    - CustomerId="'{'{{customer_id}}'}'"
    - WebServiceUri="{{uripath}}"
    - /install
    - /passive
    - /norestart
    - /S
    state: present
```

still, nothing.
Some of them won't go through, and some of them will but will install nothing.
Note that if I am to run the original script in PS or if I do just the CMD bit in a command prompt window it works perfectly.

Has any of you had to deal with this?
Thank you in advance!

I by now think I've tried pretty much everything I could find, there's even a script in github to install particularly Qualys, but I haven't found any that would have to use those arguments I'm having trouble with, I don't know if that's normal in all qualys installations.

Any advice will be much appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: `Some of them won't go through` is pretty much a synonym of `it doesn't work` which is [not an accurate description of the problem you are facing](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section

Comment: But, isn't the bits of code that I pasted here a minimal reproducible example? If I run the one in powershell (the one on top) it works without issues, I can just change the variables for the actual numbers and it passes through flawlessly, the problem is when I try to run that same (or variations of the same) script through an ansible play... all variables are OK, but it won't do anything.
Any idea?

Comment: @Nahuster You're saying the same commands work outside of Ansible perfectly?

Comment: `But, isn't the bits of code that I pasted here a minimal reproducible example?` <= not exactly as we don't have a precise definition of `it won't go through / it won't do anything`. Does the script hang forever? Does it fire an error? Does it end without any visible error? Did you run the playbook in debug mode (`-vvv`) to see if you could get any other information? Did you try adding some debug output in the script itself to debug the exact parameter received or any other command output? ...